Efficient solution of many systems of equations involving Hadamard powers
I have many matrix equations of the form
$$A^{\circ z_i}\mathbf{x}_i=\mathbf{b}_i$$
where ${\circ z_i}$ indicates the Hadamard power (element-wise). $A$ is a very large dense symmetric matrix with the diagonal elements equal to $1$.
I am trying to solve for each of the $\mathbf{x}_i$. Is there any pre-computation that can be done with $A$ to speed up the calculations?
